# my SQL statement is wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

```
    theStatement = theConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `delldb`.`campaigns`"
         + " (`CAMPAIGN_NAME`, `CAMPAIGN_CREATOR`, `CAMPAIGN_TOTALCOST`, `CAMPAIGN_DESC`, `CAMPAIGN_STARTTIME`," // 5
         + " `CAMPAIGN_ENDTIME`, `CAMPAIGN_DATE`, `CAMPAIGN_VENUEADDRESS`, `CAMPAIGN_EST_ATTENDEES`, " // 4 (9)
         + "`CAMPAIGN_MDF_REQUEST`, `CAMPAIGN_REIMBURSEMENT`, " // 2 (11)
         + "`CAMPAIGN_PARTICIPANTS`, `CAMPAIGN_EST_OPPORTUNITIES`, `CAMPAIGN_TECH_PARTNERS`, `CAMPAIGN_EST_REVENUE`, " // 4 (15)
         + "`CAMPAIGN_SOFTWARE_COMPONENT`, `CAMPAIGN_PRODUCTS_DISCUSS`, `CAMPAIGN_TARGET_AUDIENCE`, " // 3 (18)
         + " `CAMPAIGN_SUBMISSIONDATE`, `CAMPAIGN_VENUE_NAME`, `CAMPAIGN_PROGRAMTYPE`, `CAMPAIGN_CONTACT_NAME`, " // 4 (22)
         + " `CAMPAIGN_COMPANY_NAME`, `CAMPAIGN_COMPANY_ADRESS`, `CAMPAIGN_CONTACT_MAIL`, `CAMPAIGN_CONTACT_PHONE`, `CAMPAIGN_SUBMISSION_DATE` " // 5 (27)

         + " VALUES "

         + " (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,"    // 8
         + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, " // 9 (17)
         + "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "); // 10 (27)                          

         theStatement.setString(1, request.getParameter("name")); 
         theStatement.setString(2, "2");//request.getParameter("CreatorID")); 
         theStatement.setString(3, request.getParameter("projectedcost"));  
         theStatement.setString(4, "my description");//request.getParameter("desc"));  
         theStatement.setString(5, request.getParameter("starttime"));
         theStatement.setString(6, request.getParameter("endtime")); 
         theStatement.setString(7, request.getParameter("programdate")); 
         theStatement.setString(8, request.getParameter("venueaddress"));  
         theStatement.setString(9, request.getParameter("estatt"));
         theStatement.setString(10, request.getParameter("mdfrequest")); 
         theStatement.setString(11, request.getParameter("reimbursementmethod")); 
         theStatement.setString(12, request.getParameter("partners")); 
         theStatement.setString(13, request.getParameter("opportunities")); 
         theStatement.setString(14, request.getParameter("partnercontribution"));  
         theStatement.setString(15, request.getParameter("estimatedrevenue")); 
         theStatement.setString(16, request.getParameter("softwarecomponent"));   
         theStatement.setString(17, checkboxproductstodiscuss); 
         theStatement.setString(18, checkboxtypeprogram);    
         theStatement.setString(19, request.getParameter("submissiondate")); 
         theStatement.setString(20, request.getParameter("venuename")); 
         theStatement.setString(21, checkboxtargetaudience);
         theStatement.setString(22, request.getParameter("contactname")); 
         theStatement.setString(23, request.getParameter("company"));  
         theStatement.setString(24, request.getParameter("companyadress"));  
         theStatement.setString(25, request.getParameter("contactemail")); 
         theStatement.setString(26, request.getParameter("contactphone")); 
         theStatement.setString(27,  request.getParameter("submissiondate"));
```

I cant really find the fault with this? whats the problem with this SQL statement? help would be gladly appreciated. (it did work before this way) i just cant seem to find out the fault.

i get this error

> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that orresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES  ('a',
>   '2', '123', 'my description', '12', '13', '2005-11-11', 'ee', '121' at
>   line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add closing bracket after column list:

```
INSERT INTO tab(column_list) VALUES (...);
```

In your example:

```
 + " `CAMPAIGN_COMPANY_NAME`, `CAMPAIGN_COMPANY_ADRESS`, `CAMPAIGN_CONTACT_MAIL`, `CAMPAIGN_CONTACT_PHONE`, `CAMPAIGN_SUBMISSION_DATE`) " // 5 (27)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, been overlooking that for the past hour now :-) Cheers and thanks :-)